# Queue::fake not work with Laravel5 codeception module

Tags: php, laravel, codeception

I write test for Laravel app with codeception and modules [Laravel5](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5), [REST](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST).

One of api test:

```
public function testEmailRegistration(ApiTester $I) {

...

// Not correct data
$I->sendPOST($route, [
    'first_name' => (string)$this->faker->randomNumber(),
    'password' => $this->faker->password(1, 7),
    'email' => 'not_valid_email',
]);

$I->seeResponseCodeIs(HttpCode::UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);

// Correct data
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::fake();

$I->sendPOST($route, [
    'first_name' => $firstName,
    'password' => $password,
    'email' => $email,
]);

\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::assertPushed(\App\Jobs\SendEmail::class);

...

}
```

I send requests on incorrect and correct data and make some assertions. In addition I check, that job is present in queue.

After execute test I give error:

```
[Error] Call to undefined method Illuminate\Queue\SyncQueue::assertPushed()
```

After `Queue:fake` facade `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue` must resolves to `QueueFake`, but in fact is still `QueueManager`, thus `assertPushed` function is undefined.

Execution of `$I->sendPOST()` reset call `Queue::fake`. It happened in laravel 5 module `\Codeception\Lib\Connector\Laravel5`, method `doRequest`.

```
protected function doRequest($request)
{
        if (!$this->firstRequest) {
            $this->initialize($request);
        }
        $this->firstRequest = false;

        $this->applyBindings();
        $this->applyContextualBindings();
        $this->applyInstances();
        $this->applyApplicationHandlers();

        $request = Request::createFromBase($request);
        $response = $this->kernel->handle($request);
        $this->app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->terminate($request, $response);

        return $response;
}
```

Each call of `doRequest` except the first init app again and some configurations as `Queue::fake` are cleared.

One of decision is one request per test. Is there another variant to work `Queue::fake` when in test make more then one request?

Comment: If you can figure out how to fix, please make pull request to https://github.com/Codeception/module-laravel5/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the Laravel module does this but I found a work-around that allows you to use fakes:

```php
public function someTest(ApiTester $I): void
{
    // what the SomeFacade::fake method call does is basically create
    // a fake object and swaps it for the original implementation in 
    // the app container, so the we're recreating that behavior here
    // only this will be persisted even after the request is issued:
    $notification_fake = new NotificationFake();
    // `haveInstance` is a method from Laravel Codeception Module 
    // which sets an object in the app container for you:
    $I->haveInstance(ChannelManager::class, $notification_fake);

    // making the request
    $I->sendPUT('some url', $some_payload);

    // assertions
    $I->canSeeResponseCodeIs(Response::HTTP_OK);
    $notification_fake->assertSentToTimes($expected_user, MyNotification::class, 1);
}
```

note that this test method is only for illustrative purposes and it misses so of the details, hence the undefined variables and such.

Also note that I user the notification fake which get registered at `Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager`, unlike most fakes that you can register under their aliased name e.g. `queue`. So you have to check what is being instantiated and how to swap it on your own. You can either find this in respective service providers for each service. **Most** of the time it's lowercase name of the facade.